# Is a struct of one element compatible with the element itself?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have the following struct:

```
struct Foo { int a; };
```

Is the code bellow conforming with the C++ Standard? I mean, can't it generate an "Undefined Behavior"?

```
Foo foo;
int ifoo;

foo = *reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&ifoo);

void bar(int value);

bar(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&foo));

auto fptr = static_cast<void(*)(...)>(&bar);
fptr(foo);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the struct may have more stringent alignment requirements than the int, so you run into UB when you reinterpret from `int` to `Foo`. I'm not sure about the other way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

9.2/20 in N3290 says

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

And your Foo is a standard-layout class.

So your second cast is correct.

I see no guarantee that the first one is correct (and I've used architecture where a char had weaker alignment restriction than a struct containing just a char, on such an architecture, it would be problematic). What the standard guarantee is that if you have a pointer to int which really point to the first element of a struct, you can reinterpret_cast it back to pointer to the struct.

Likewise, I see nothing which would make your third one defined if it was a reinterpret_cast (I'm pretty sure that some ABI use different convention to pass structs and basic types, so it is highly suspicious and I'd need a clear mention in the standard to accept it) and I'm quite sure that nothing allow static_cast between pointers to functions.

Comment: Does it mean that struct can't have more strict alignment than its initial member? If so, does that mean that pointers to struct must be at least as wide as `char *`?

Comment: Oh, and +1 for the only answer that actually cites the standard.

Comment: @avakar, oops, I misread the first example, I fixed my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Both reinterpret_casts are fine. 5.2.10-7 says this behaves a chain of static casts, like `static_cast<Foo*>( static_cast<void*>(&ifoo ) )`, which for standard layout types is well defined. Don't confuse casting to an `int*` as being somehow related to casting to an `int` where the guarantees are quite different.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, you forgot the part "if the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1".  I'd like citation for the fact that the alignment requirements of a struct aren't stricter than those of its first member, even if it is just for the limited case of a struct with only one member. (As I wrote, that would make some implementations I've used non conforming; I'm pretty sure it was conforming previously but C++11 has a lot of new text concerning alignment, I've perhaps missed a new requirement.)

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, note that the possibility to form pointer to incomplete struct would make it inconvenient (all pointer to struct would be the same size as pointer to void). I'm beginning to be of the opinion that if C++11 allows that, it warrants a defect report to ensure it was desired.

Comment: For std.layout, `&foo.a` must be the same address as `&foo` (9.2-21). A reinterpret_cast using the member directly is clearly defined, and safe. Now 3.9.2-3 says if the address is valid it doesn't matter where it came from. 9.2-21 also mentions alignment padding must not come before the first member. Between these two requirements would this not be the implicit requirement about alignment?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, you are repeating the same mistake I did (and avakar pointer to me).  The problem isn't with a round trip (which is guaranteed, I wrote so), but with `reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(&ifoo)` where `ifoo` is just an `int`, not the first member of a `Foo`.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about round-trip, but I think I see the problem. It may be simpler than alignment, there is no guarantee that `sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(int)` thus obviously using an int as a Foo would be wrong. As to alignment, I think you/avakar are also right, even if the size if the same there is no requirement about the alignment requirement of the struct being the same as its first element. Thus my initial comment is wrong, and you are correct that only the second cast is valid.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you access only the first element of a struct, it's considered to be safe, since there's no padding before the first member of a struct. In fact, this trick is used, for example, in the Objecive-C runtime, where a generic pointer type is defined as:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

and in runtime, real objecs (which are still bare struct pointers) have memory layouts like this:

```
struct {
    Class isa;
    int x; // random other data as instance variables
} *CustomObject;
```

and the runtime accesses the class of an actual object using this method.

Comment: That technique is similar to what was used in [BOOPSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOOPSI) on the old Amiga.

Comment: You are technically correct, but you've only answered half of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Foo is a plain-old-data structure, which means it contains nothing but the data you explicitely store in it. In this case: an int.
Thus the memory layout for an int and Foo are the same.

You can typecast from one to the other without problems. Whether it's a clever idea to use this kind of stuff is a different question.

PS: 
This **usually** works, but not necessarily due to different alignment restrictions. See AProgrammer's answer.

Comment: But... `reinterpret_cast`? Really?

Comment: @MrLister: What's wrong with `reinterpret_cast`? It's exactly for this kind of stuff - reinterpreting one thing as another.

Comment: The standard requires that a pointer to a POD struct is identical to the pointer to its first element.

Comment: -1 the answer is incorrect due to alignment issues. See AProgrammer's answer.